# Postgresql function with the provided name/arguments doesn't exist, but it does

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

I just cannot call a function in Posgresql 10. I am using npgsql package with Asp.net Core 2.0. I used this function some time ago and it worked. I altered it to include one more integer argument and now it is impossible to call it. I removed all the datatypes that thought could cause problems (dates) but I couldn't spot the problem. Postgresql is by far the database I have the least afinity.

[visual studio error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6fE6.png)

The exception says that I am calling a function like this (I copied it from visual studio)

```
function public.sp_cadastrar_pedido(param_cliente_id => integer, 
param_numero_parcelas => integer, param_numero_transacao => integer, 
param_total => numeric, param_nome_cartao => character, 
param_numero_cartao => character, param_endereco_id => integer,
 param_forma_pagamento => integer, param_codigo_seguranca => character)
```

That's from the definition my function (I copied it from PgAdmin)

[my function pgadmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFsLT.png)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.sp_cadastrar_pedido(
    param_cliente_id integer,
    param_numero_parcelas integer,
    param_numero_transacao integer,
    param_total numeric,
    param_nome_cartao character,
    param_numero_cartao character,
    param_endereco_id integer,
    param_forma_pagamento integer,
    param_codigo_seguranca character)
```

My c# code, I was using AddWithValue method of the command and changed to use the Add method to see if it solved to problem, but no solution. I checked the values being passed on the debugger  and they are all good, apparently.

```
 cmd.CommandText = "public.sp_cadastrar_pedido";
                    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@param_cliente_id", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer).Value = dadosPedido.ClienteId;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@param_numero_parcelas", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer).Value = dadosPedido.NumeroParcelas;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@param_numero_transacao", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer).Value = dadosPedido.NumeroTransacao;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@param_total", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Numeric).Value = dadosPedido.Total;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@param_nome_cartao", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Char).Value = dadosPedido.NomeCartao;


                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@param_numero_cartao", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Char).Value = dadosPedido.NumeroCartao;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@param_endereco_id", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer).Value = dadosPedido.Endereco.EnderecoId;
                    //     cmd.Parameters.Add("@param_data_validade_cartao", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Date, 20).Value = dadosPedido.DataValidadeCartao.Date;
                    //   cmd.Parameters.Add("@param_data_nascimento", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Date, 20).Value = dadosPedido.DataNascimento.Date;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@param_forma_pagamento", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer).Value = 0;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@param_codigo_seguranca", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Char).Value = dadosPedido.CodigoSeguranca;
```

Comment: Does it work for a function without parameters? And for a function with 1 parameter? Are you reusing an earlier `cmd` that has parameters from the previous call?

Comment: Also try looking at your PG log to see what exactly the failure was.

Comment: I am so ashamed! I was connecting to the development database instead of the production. But let me explain, I had some really hard time when using Datetime datatype as a parameter sometime ago and I kind kept this problem in mind so I was sure that it was npgsql that was causing the error. I didn't post the question right away the problem occured I spent 4 hours testing the function, modifying it, calling it directly on Pgadmin and didn't think about checking if I was querying the right database.